# How to save files locally on host machine Docker Windows

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-volume

I am working on a Python Flask app that serves a simple UI and generates some files that needs to be saved permanently while using a Docker container. Right now, and for development purposes, I'm saving these files locally in my project's repo (specifically in `C:/Users/marsolmo/Desktop/repo/src/data` folder).

The main script that runs the Flask is `app.py` and the directories tree in the `repo` looks like this:

```
repo
|-- src
|    |-- data 
|    |    +-- file1.csv
|    |    +-- file2.csv
|    |    +-- file3.csv
|    +-- app.py
|
+-- Dockerfile
+-- README.md
```

I need to deploy this app in a Docker container on a Windows machine and save these files into a specific folder of the host machine (i.e. `C:/DockerData/app/data`). I have tried to mount a volume on the docker container by doing `docker run -v C:\DockerData\app\data:C:\Users\marsolmos\Desktop\repo\src\data <IMAGE_ID>`, but it doesn't work. When I run this command it returns the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: \Users\marsolmos\Desktop\repo\src\data.
```

The files are being saved into the local folder `repo/src/data` of the repo but not in `C:/DockerData/app/data`.

How can I do this on Windows?

Comment: the `-v` syntax is `-v host-path:container-path` -> try `-v C:\DockerData\app\data:/path/to/repo/src/data`. are you using wsl2? you might need to specify your host path as /mnt/c/DockerData/app/data instead

Comment: Hi @jemand771 I've tried the `-v C:\DockerData\app\data:/path/to/repo/src/data` option but it returns an error. Please check edited question to see the error message